# Can't initialize state_machined class that belongs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer, state-machine

I've included state_machine in my class and got exited while manipulating with it in the console. However, my excitement gone when I tried to use it in an application. I got

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

error in "initialize" method of my state_machined class "request" when I call user.requests.build.

"initialize" method looks like

```
def initialize
  super()
end
```

because the gem's creator told me so at https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine. Class definition starts with

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :subject, :details, :assigned_to, :log, :status, :solution

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assigned_to"
```

I think that the error caused by associations that the initializer are not aware of. Am I right? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given in the README was not for ActiveRecord integrations -- just for plain Ruby classes.  In an ActiveRecord integration there's no need to do anything special in your initialize method in order for state_machine to work.  By overriding your initialize method, you're changing the method signature that ActiveRecord depends on.  If you're not doing anything else in that override, I suggest you remove it altogether.

Hope this helps!